# How to wrap some computed values in a range in order to allow using join on the output of transform?

Tags: c++, functional-programming, c++17, monads, range-v3

### The original question

I have a piece of code where I process a `std::vector` by splitting it into groups and processing each group.

An `if`-`else` determines the processing each group undergoes:

- groups taking the `if` branch will end up giving a single ouptut,
- groups taking the `else` branch give rise to several outputs.

All these outputs are collected in a vector.

This is a simplification of the code:

```cpp
#include <range/v3/view/group_by.hpp>
#include <vector>

namespace rv = ranges::views;

auto f1 = [](auto){ return 7; /* this actually does depend on the input */ };
auto f2 = [](auto){ return 9; /* this actually does depend on the input */ };
auto f3 = [](auto){ return 5; /* this actually does depend on the input */ };
auto f4 = [](auto){ return 8; /* this actually does depend on the input */ };

int main() {
    // input
    std::vector<int> v{1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2};

    // prepare output
    std::vector<int> w; // and resize appropriately

    // populate w in a loop
    for (auto g : v | rv::group_by(std::equal_to<>{})) {
        if (g.front() != 3) {
            // for these groups only one item is stored into w
            w.push_back(f1(g));
        } else {
            // for these groups several items are stored into w
            w.push_back(f2(g));
            w.push_back(f3(g));
            w.push_back(f4(g));
        }
    }
}
```

I can't help but think that, after all, I'm just doing monadic binding, i.e.

- transforming the output of `group_by`, group by group,
- where each group can result in

  - a sequence of several elements (`else` branch)
  - a single element (`if` branch), which can be tought of as a one-element sequence
- joining the sequences

Therefore, I'd be tempted to simplify the code as follows:

```cpp
#include <range/v3/view/join.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/transform.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/group_by.hpp>
#include <vector>

namespace rv = ranges::views;

auto f = [](auto x){
    auto one = std::vector<int>{7};
    auto many = std::vector<int>{9,5,8};
    return (x.front() != 3) ? one
                            : many;
};

int main() {

    std::vector<int> v{1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2};

    auto w = v | rv::group_by(std::equal_to<>{})
               | rv::transform(f)
               | rv::join;
}
```

This code, however, doesn't work because `f` is not returning views for each group, but rather true `std::vector`s.

In some way, I think, I would need to wrap the single `7` and the `9,5,8` into a range, so that `join` can make its job.

How can I do that?

### Update after some time

The fact of the matter is that I'm hitting [The Surprising Limitations of C++ Ranges Beyond Trivial Cases](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2019/09/13/the-surprising-limitations-of-c-ranges-beyond-trivial-use-cases/).

However, in that article there's a link to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60415631/5825294) here on SO which is indeed an answer to my question too, which consists in changing this

```cpp
    auto w = v | rv::group_by(std::equal_to<>{})
               | rv::transform(f)
               | rv::join;
```

to this

```cpp
    auto w = v | rv::group_by(std::equal_to<>{})
               | rv::transform(f)
               | rv::cache1
               | rv::join;
```

where `cache1` caches the results of `transform` thus preventing `join` from storing dangling references after the temporary `std::vector`s are gone.

Comment: If the two vectors were declared const in the global scope, returning a range is trivial.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy, no, they are not. They are computed based on the inputs.

Comment: I'm trying to understand your code but have no idea what the `|` operator does with a vector, and so far I have not been able to find relevant documentation.

Comment: If you refer to the `|` in front of `rv::join`, it doesn't work, and that's the reason the code doesn't compile. If you refer to `|` in general, that's the pipe operator; search for _Range adaptors_ [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges).